# No Name for Selected Tab in Mobile Web

Tags: bug, mobile-web

For some reason on the mobile web, the selected tab that determines the questions that pop up (active, newest, featured, unanswered...) doesn't show on the mobile site:

[image]

It is kinda weird and it is not helpful at all. Can the name of the selected tab come back please?

This is not a dupe because whether there is the message or not, the selected tab name does not show up.